# pexpect.expect() in python3 is throwing error as "must be in str , not bytes"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pexpect

I am migrating my code to python 3.4.3. This code works fine in python 2.4.3. but here it throws error in python 3.4.3.
should I use anything different from expect ?
Here is my code snippet which gets the error:

```
   telconn=pexpect.spawn('telnet 10.24.12.83')
    telconn.logfile = sys.stdout
    login=telconn.expect([":","key to proceed.",">"])
    if login==0:
        telconn.send("user1" + "\r")
        telconn.expect(":")
        telconn.send("paswd1" + "\r\r\r\r\n\n\n")
        login1=telconn.expect([">","key to proceed."])
        if login1==0:
            print("nothing")
        elif login1==1:
            telconn.expect("key to proceed.")
            telconn.send ("\003")
            telconn.expect(">")
    if login==1:
        telconn.send ("\003")
        telconn.expect(">")
        print("ctlc")
    elif login==2:
        telconn.send("\n\r")
        telconn.expect(">")
```

The error what I get is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cleanup1.py", line 128, in <module>
    Connect()
  File "cleanup1.py", line 53, in Connect
    login=telconn.expect([":","key to proceed.",">"])
  File "/corp/global/install-dependent/python/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 315, in expect
    timeout, searchwindowsize, async)
  File "/corp/global/install-dependent/python/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 339, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "/corp/global/install-dependent/python/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 97, in expect_loop
    incoming = spawn.read_nonblocking(spawn.maxread, timeout)
  File "/corp/global/install-dependent/python/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 455, in read_nonblocking
    return super(spawn, self).read_nonblocking(size)
  File "/corp/global/install-dependent/python/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 157, in read_nonblocking
    self._log(s, 'read')
  File "/corp/global/install-dependent/python/3.4.3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 115, in _log
    self.logfile.write(s)
TypeError: must be str, not bytes
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`pexpect` wants to log bytes, not decoded strings. You can just let it do that:

```
telconn.logfile = sys.stdout.buffer
```

`sys.stdout` defaults to expecting strings. Internal buffer is happy with bytes.

Answer (score 19):

The accepted answer is correct in that you're currently trying to log bytes and not string. But at least as of pexpect version 4.6, you can [provide the `encoding` argument to `spawn`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#spawn-class). So use:

```
telconn=pexpect.spawn('telnet 10.24.12.83', encoding='utf-8')
```

Then all communication with the spawned terminal is automatically decoded using utf-8, and you'll be able to use `telconn.logfile = sys.stdout`.

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted, as no further change is required on handling the spawn object.

Comment: For some reason I'm still getting the error regardless of specifying the encoding in spawn.

Answer (score 4):

As of this [bug report](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/159) you should use `spawnu` instead of `spawn` to write unicode instead of bytes. You might not have known that `spawn` uses binary logfiles, and `spawnu` uses unicode logfiles.

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted, as no further change is required on handling the spawn object.

Comment: This answer is better than the one from @Kyle Barron, because the refactoring is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

change line number 53 to

```
login1=telconn.expect(">"+"key to proceed.")
```