# System not responding to pexpect commands

Tags: python, networking, pexpect

I'm trying to write very simple program which controls remote machine using pexpect. But remote system does not react to sent commands.

Here is source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pexpect
import sys
child = pexpect.spawn('telnet 192.168.2.81 24')
res = child.expect('/ # ')
print(res)
res = child.sendline('touch foo')
print(res)
```

Here is output:

```
0
10
```

So, as far as I understand, commands are executed successfully but there is no result on target system, i.e. foo file is not created.

Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following line after `pexpect.spawn()` or you would see nothing.

```
# for Python 2
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout

# for Python 3
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer
```

You also need the following statements at the end (otherwise the script would immediately exit after `sendline('touch foo')` so `touch foo` does not have a chance to run):

```
child.sendline('exit')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

---

According to the manual:

> The `logfile_read` and `logfile_send` members can be used to separately log the input from the child and output sent to the child. Sometimes you don’t want to see everything you write to the child. You only want to log what the child sends back. For example:
>
> ```
> child = pexpect.spawn('some_command')
> child.logfile_read = sys.stdout
> ```

Comment: Thank you! `child.sendline('exit')` and `child.expect(pexpect.EOF)` worked. What about `child.logfile_read = sys.stdout` - it leads to error `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`, but I don't see any profit from it even if it worked, so I think I could ignore it and use only recommendations related to the end of file.

Comment: found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35330424/expect-in-python3-is-throwing-error-as-must-be-in-str-not-bytes . updated my answer.